# MySQL: Like with comma and points

Tags: mysql, search, sql-like

I got a row with a floating number like 39.93

Now I would like to perform a search; in this case the input "39.93" should result in a match AND the input "39,93" should also match.

At the moment I got the following code:

```
$query->where('(a.id LIKE ' . $search . ' OR a.number LIKE ' . $search . 'OR sum LIKE ' .  $search . ' OR userid LIKE ' . $search . ' OR c.lastname LIKE ' . $search . ' OR c.firstname LIKE ' . $search . ')');
```

In this case I'm looking for "sum" to match on "39,93", too.

How can I do that?

Comment: I think you want [rlike](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html)

Comment: use a regex. `where sum regexp '[0-9][0-9](.|,)[0-9][0-9]'`

Comment: Hi there  - thanks for your postings, but I've got one more problem with that: I do not want to list any result where x,xx or x.xx matches; I would like to search a specific row, where 1,23/1.23 matches for example. These value (1,23/1.23) is given by an html-input-field.

How can I solve that?